# Why is this my jQuery function firing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i'm trying to create a small personal use jQuery plugin. I have the function completed but the setInterval() function fires twice for some reason and I can't seem to figure out why. At first it seems like it doesn't fire twice but I know by testing (adding an alert on each trigger of the interval) that it fires twice, on the example [here](http://dans.comuv.com/tests.php) you can see that it gradually gets faster and faster (after about 2 minutes it'll be really fast) this is the result of it firing twice.

Can someone please help me how to fix this?

The Javascript code:

```
(function( $ ) {

  $.fn.imageSwap = function(img) {
  var src = this.attr("src");
  var id = this;
  id.fadeToggle("fast", function(){
  id.attr("src", img);
  id.fadeToggle("fast");
  });
  return this;
  };

 })( jQuery );



(function( $ ) {

  $.fn.slideShow = function(array, time) {
  var i = -1;
  var num = array.length;
  var id=this;

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
  i++
  if(i>(num)-1){i=0}
  id.imageSwap(array[i]);
  },time);

  };
```

The page code:

```
<script>

$("#slideshow").slideShow([
"http://www.rta.nsw.gov.au/licensing/images/dkt_faqs/number1.gif",
"http://www.rta.nsw.gov.au/licensing/images/dkt_faqs/number2.gif",
"http://www.rta.nsw.gov.au/licensing/images/dkt_faqs/number3.gif",
"http://www.rta.nsw.gov.au/licensing/images/dkt_faqs/number4.gif"
], 1000);

</script>

<img id="slideshow" src=""/>
```

Comment: is it possibly somewhat related to something like this? (setInterval without an equivalent clearInterval) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266265/image-flickering-with-setinterval-function/12266329#12266329

Comment: You may be calling `.slideShow()` more than once in your code either directly or indirectly

Comment: maybe you need a return false ?

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I've looked through all my code and can't find anywhere that i've called the function again. That's why I was hoping someone could possibly help me find that or another issue

Comment: I suspect fadeToggle() to be responsable of this unexpected behaviour. Have you got same result using fadeOut/fadeIn ?

Comment: I don't see it getting any faster...

Comment: I instrumented `setInterval` and `clearInterval` as fast as I could (code, copy, refresh, paste). I saw an immense number of `setInterval`s getting called, but not a single `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 2):

I narrowed the problem here and noticed it was only happening when I switched tabs. So, a bit of searching revealed some things.

By design it seems that Chrome stacks up the `setInterval` calls. So, when you return to the inactive tab it just happens to run them in a row.

You can see some workarounds in other related questions in SO:

- [When using setInterval, if I switch tabs in Chrome and go back, the slider goes crazy catching up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6183463/417685)
- [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927284/417685)